# Indexing failed on not loaded collection of entities and breaks transaction with LazyInitializationException

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I load an entity in my UI, change several things and update my entity with a new transaction, but Hibernate Search intercept within my transaction and try to update search index. That would be find, except it tries to load an collection that is annotated with `@IndexedEmbedded()` that was not used and so will throw an `LazyInitializationException`.

How I can prevent this?

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error while indexing in Hibernate Search (before transaction completion) 
    at org.hibernate.search.event.impl.EventSourceTransactionContext$DelegateToSynchronizationOnBeforeTx.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(EventSourceTransactionContext.java:173) 
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:954) 
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:525) 
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2480) 
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473) 
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:178) 
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:39) 
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:98) 
        ... 76 common frames omitted 
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: de.foo.Bar, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:597) 
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:216) 
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:576) 
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:147) 
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:188) 
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.buildDocumentFieldsForEmbeddedObjects(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:553) 
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.buildDocumentFields(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:482) 
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.buildDocumentFieldsForEmbeddedObjects(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:593) 
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.buildDocumentFields(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:482) 
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.getDocument(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:402) 
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.createAddWork(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:299) 
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.addWorkToQueue(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:241) 
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.impl.WorkPlan$PerEntityWork.enqueueLuceneWork(WorkPlan.java:560) 
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.impl.WorkPlan$PerClassWork.enqueueLuceneWork(WorkPlan.java:322) 
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.impl.WorkPlan.getPlannedLuceneWork(WorkPlan.java:188) 
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.WorkQueue.prepareWorkPlan(WorkQueue.java:115) 
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.BatchedQueueingProcessor.prepareWorks(BatchedQueueingProcessor.java:55) 
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.PostTransactionWorkQueueSynchronization.beforeCompletion(PostTransactionWorkQueueSynchronization.java:67) 
    at org.hibernate.search.event.impl.EventSourceTransactionContext$DelegateToSynchronizationOnBeforeTx.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(EventSourceTransactionContext.java:170) 
        ... 84 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

When this happens, it generally means you closed the session that was used to load the entity, and tried to update the entity using another session.
It happens in some frameworks where you need to serialize the entities between the loading and the actual update, for some reason.

The easiest solution is: don't detach and use entities across different sessions, it'll just bring you headaches. And I'm not talking about just Hibernate Search.

If you really want to do it, [it's possible](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-persist-and-merge/), but not as obvious as it might first seem.

There are ways to avoid using detached entities in Wicket, at least. For other frameworks, without knowing more about your UI framework, I can't really help. I doubt I can help if it's a UI framework I don't know, but it's worth a shot ;)

If you decide to provide more information, please at least mention: the Hibernate ORM and Hibernate Search versions you're using, and the exact code you use when interacting with the Session/EntityManager (`.persist()`, `.merge()`, `.saveOrUpdate()`, ...), and the UI code related to storing/transferring the entity between components.